# QGIS graphical modeller naming layer output based on attribute

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler

I have built a model in QGIS that buffers some points and then clips them to a paddock boundary. I would like to use the Load Layer Into Project tool or the Rename Layer tool to name the layers output based on the paddocks name but I can't figure out how to do it.

I have been trying to use the precalucated value option for the output but maybe I am not getting the syntax right?

I have tried all sort of variations of `attribute( $currentfeature,"Name")`   or `attribute( @Paddock, Name)` I can think of.
In the expression dialog I get:

> No feature was found on this layer to evaluate the expression.

The message from the log when running the model is:

> Invalid (empty) layer name
> Error encountered while running Load layer into project
> Execution failed after 0.09 seconds

An model of what I am trying to do is below:

```
<!DOCTYPE model>
<Option type="Map">
  <Option name="children" type="Map">
    <Option name="native:buffer_1" type="Map">
      <Option value="true" name="active" type="bool"/>
      <Option name="alg_config"/>
      <Option value="native:buffer" name="alg_id" type="QString"/>
      <Option value="" name="color" type="QString"/>
      <Option name="comment" type="Map">
        <Option value="" name="color" type="QString"/>
        <Option value="" name="component_description" type="QString"/>
        <Option value="60" name="component_height" type="double"/>
        <Option value="320" name="component_pos_x" type="double"/>
        <Option value="115" name="component_pos_y" type="double"/>
        <Option value="100" name="component_width" type="double"/>
        <Option value="true" name="outputs_collapsed" type="bool"/>
        <Option value="true" name="parameters_collapsed" type="bool"/>
      </Option>
      <Option value="Buffer" name="component_description" type="QString"/>
      <Option value="30" name="component_height" type="double"/>
      <Option value="544" name="component_pos_x" type="double"/>
      <Option value="337" name="component_pos_y" type="double"/>
      <Option value="200" name="component_width" type="double"/>
      <Option name="dependencies"/>
      <Option value="native:buffer_1" name="id" type="QString"/>
      <Option name="outputs"/>
      <Option value="true" name="outputs_collapsed" type="bool"/>
      <Option value="true" name="parameters_collapsed" type="bool"/>
      <Option name="params" type="Map">
        <Option name="DISSOLVE" type="List">
          <Option type="Map">
            <Option value="2" name="source" type="int"/>
            <Option value="true" name="static_value" type="bool"/>
          </Option>
        </Option>
        <Option name="DISTANCE" type="List">
          <Option type="Map">
            <Option value="2" name="source" type="int"/>
            <Option value="1000" name="static_value" type="double"/>
          </Option>
        </Option>
        <Option name="END_CAP_STYLE" type="List">
          <Option type="Map">
            <Option value="2" name="source" type="int"/>
            <Option value="0" name="static_value" type="int"/>
          </Option>
        </Option>
        <Option name="INPUT" type="List">
          <Option type="Map">
            <Option value="PointsLayer" name="parameter_name" type="QString"/>
            <Option value="0" name="source" type="int"/>
          </Option>
        </Option>
        <Option name="JOIN_STYLE" type="List">
          <Option type="Map">
            <Option value="2" name="source" type="int"/>
            <Option value="0" name="static_value" type="int"/>
          </Option>
        </Option>
        <Option name="MITER_LIMIT" type="List">
          <Option type="Map">
            <Option value="2" name="source" type="int"/>
            <Option value="2" name="static_value" type="double"/>
          </Option>
        </Option>
        <Option name="SEGMENTS" type="List">
          <Option type="Map">
            <Option value="2" name="source" type="int"/>
            <Option value="10" name="static_value" type="int"/>
          </Option>
        </Option>
      </Option>
    </Option>
    <Option name="native:intersection_1" type="Map">
      <Option value="true" name="active" type="bool"/>
      <Option name="alg_config"/>
      <Option value="native:intersection" name="alg_id" type="QString"/>
      <Option value="" name="color" type="QString"/>
      <Option name="comment" type="Map">
        <Option value="" name="color" type="QString"/>
        <Option value="" name="component_description" type="QString"/>
        <Option value="60" name="component_height" type="double"/>
        <Option value="1039" name="component_pos_x" type="double"/>
        <Option value="455" name="component_pos_y" type="double"/>
        <Option value="100" name="component_width" type="double"/>
        <Option value="true" name="outputs_collapsed" type="bool"/>
        <Option value="true" name="parameters_collapsed" type="bool"/>
      </Option>
      <Option value="Intersection" name="component_description" type="QString"/>
      <Option value="30" name="component_height" type="double"/>
      <Option value="802" name="component_pos_x" type="double"/>
      <Option value="207" name="component_pos_y" type="double"/>
      <Option value="200" name="component_width" type="double"/>
      <Option name="dependencies"/>
      <Option value="native:intersection_1" name="id" type="QString"/>
      <Option name="outputs"/>
      <Option value="true" name="outputs_collapsed" type="bool"/>
      <Option value="true" name="parameters_collapsed" type="bool"/>
      <Option name="params" type="Map">
        <Option name="INPUT" type="List">
          <Option type="Map">
            <Option value="native:buffer_1" name="child_id" type="QString"/>
            <Option value="OUTPUT" name="output_name" type="QString"/>
            <Option value="1" name="source" type="int"/>
          </Option>
        </Option>
        <Option name="INPUT_FIELDS" type="List">
          <Option type="Map">
            <Option value="2" name="source" type="int"/>
            <Option name="static_value" type="StringList">
              <Option value="" type="QString"/>
            </Option>
          </Option>
        </Option>
        <Option name="OVERLAY" type="List">
          <Option type="Map">
            <Option value="VactorLayer" name="parameter_name" type="QString"/>
            <Option value="0" name="source" type="int"/>
          </Option>
        </Option>
        <Option name="OVERLAY_FIELDS" type="List">
          <Option type="Map">
            <Option value="2" name="source" type="int"/>
            <Option name="static_value" type="StringList">
              <Option value="" type="QString"/>
            </Option>
          </Option>
        </Option>
        <Option name="OVERLAY_FIELDS_PREFIX" type="List">
          <Option type="Map">
            <Option value="2" name="source" type="int"/>
            <Option value="" name="static_value" type="QString"/>
          </Option>
        </Option>
      </Option>
    </Option>
    <Option name="native:loadlayer_1" type="Map">
      <Option value="true" name="active" type="bool"/>
      <Option name="alg_config"/>
      <Option value="native:loadlayer" name="alg_id" type="QString"/>
      <Option value="" name="color" type="QString"/>
      <Option name="comment" type="Map">
        <Option value="" name="color" type="QString"/>
        <Option value="" name="component_description" type="QString"/>
        <Option value="60" name="component_height" type="double"/>
        <Option value="1442" name="component_pos_x" type="double"/>
        <Option value="554" name="component_pos_y" type="double"/>
        <Option value="100" name="component_width" type="double"/>
        <Option value="true" name="outputs_collapsed" type="bool"/>
        <Option value="true" name="parameters_collapsed" type="bool"/>
      </Option>
      <Option value="Doesn't Work" name="component_description" type="QString"/>
      <Option value="30" name="component_height" type="double"/>
      <Option value="957" name="component_pos_x" type="double"/>
      <Option value="315" name="component_pos_y" type="double"/>
      <Option value="200" name="component_width" type="double"/>
      <Option name="dependencies"/>
      <Option value="native:loadlayer_1" name="id" type="QString"/>
      <Option name="outputs"/>
      <Option value="true" name="outputs_collapsed" type="bool"/>
      <Option value="true" name="parameters_collapsed" type="bool"/>
      <Option name="params" type="Map">
        <Option name="INPUT" type="List">
          <Option type="Map">
            <Option value="native:intersection_1" name="child_id" type="QString"/>
            <Option value="OUTPUT" name="output_name" type="QString"/>
            <Option value="1" name="source" type="int"/>
          </Option>
        </Option>
        <Option name="NAME" type="List">
          <Option type="Map">
            <Option value=" attribute($currentfeature , 'Name')" name="expression" type="QString"/>
            <Option value="3" name="source" type="int"/>
          </Option>
        </Option>
      </Option>
    </Option>
    <Option name="native:loadlayer_2" type="Map">
      <Option value="true" name="active" type="bool"/>
      <Option name="alg_config"/>
      <Option value="native:loadlayer" name="alg_id" type="QString"/>
      <Option value="" name="color" type="QString"/>
      <Option name="comment" type="Map">
        <Option value="" name="color" type="QString"/>
        <Option value="" name="component_description" type="QString"/>
        <Option value="60" name="component_height" type="double"/>
        <Option value="1451" name="component_pos_x" type="double"/>
        <Option value="576" name="component_pos_y" type="double"/>
        <Option value="100" name="component_width" type="double"/>
        <Option value="true" name="outputs_collapsed" type="bool"/>
        <Option value="true" name="parameters_collapsed" type="bool"/>
      </Option>
      <Option value="Works" name="component_description" type="QString"/>
      <Option value="30" name="component_height" type="double"/>
      <Option value="916" name="component_pos_x" type="double"/>
      <Option value="413" name="component_pos_y" type="double"/>
      <Option value="200" name="component_width" type="double"/>
      <Option name="dependencies"/>
      <Option value="native:loadlayer_2" name="id" type="QString"/>
      <Option name="outputs"/>
      <Option value="true" name="outputs_collapsed" type="bool"/>
      <Option value="true" name="parameters_collapsed" type="bool"/>
      <Option name="params" type="Map">
        <Option name="INPUT" type="List">
          <Option type="Map">
            <Option value="native:intersection_1" name="child_id" type="QString"/>
            <Option value="OUTPUT" name="output_name" type="QString"/>
            <Option value="1" name="source" type="int"/>
          </Option>
        </Option>
        <Option name="NAME" type="List">
          <Option type="Map">
            <Option value="2" name="source" type="int"/>
            <Option value="Name" name="static_value" type="QString"/>
          </Option>
        </Option>
      </Option>
    </Option>
  </Option>
  <Option name="designerParameterValues" type="Map">
    <Option value="Point_e7a64aeb_f9a0_4250_a604_9f34e49de051" name="PointsLayer" type="QString"/>
    <Option value="true" name="VERBOSE_LOG" type="bool"/>
    <Option value="Polygon_81f8e358_ced8_4547_bf70_a02d1dbb28b8" name="VactorLayer" type="QString"/>
  </Option>
  <Option name="groupBoxes"/>
  <Option name="help"/>
  <Option name="modelVariables"/>
  <Option value="Test" name="model_group" type="QString"/>
  <Option value="Name Layer" name="model_name" type="QString"/>
  <Option name="parameterDefinitions" type="Map">
    <Option name="PointsLayer" type="Map">
      <Option name="data_types" type="List">
        <Option value="0" type="int"/>
      </Option>
      <Option name="default" type="invalid"/>
      <Option name="defaultGui" type="invalid"/>
      <Option value="Points Layer" name="description" type="QString"/>
      <Option value="0" name="flags" type="int"/>
      <Option value="" name="help" type="QString"/>
      <Option name="metadata"/>
      <Option value="PointsLayer" name="name" type="QString"/>
      <Option value="vector" name="parameter_type" type="QString"/>
    </Option>
    <Option name="VactorLayer" type="Map">
      <Option name="data_types" type="List">
        <Option value="2" type="int"/>
      </Option>
      <Option name="default" type="invalid"/>
      <Option name="defaultGui" type="invalid"/>
      <Option value="Polygon Layer" name="description" type="QString"/>
      <Option value="0" name="flags" type="int"/>
      <Option value="" name="help" type="QString"/>
      <Option name="metadata"/>
      <Option value="VactorLayer" name="name" type="QString"/>
      <Option value="vector" name="parameter_type" type="QString"/>
    </Option>
  </Option>
  <Option name="parameterOrder"/>
  <Option name="parameters" type="Map">
    <Option name="PointsLayer" type="Map">
      <Option value="" name="color" type="QString"/>
      <Option name="comment" type="Map">
        <Option value="" name="color" type="QString"/>
        <Option value="" name="component_description" type="QString"/>
        <Option value="60" name="component_height" type="double"/>
        <Option value="433" name="component_pos_x" type="double"/>
        <Option value="407" name="component_pos_y" type="double"/>
        <Option value="100" name="component_width" type="double"/>
        <Option value="true" name="outputs_collapsed" type="bool"/>
        <Option value="true" name="parameters_collapsed" type="bool"/>
      </Option>
      <Option value="PointsLayer" name="component_description" type="QString"/>
      <Option value="30" name="component_height" type="double"/>
      <Option value="212" name="component_pos_x" type="double"/>
      <Option value="333" name="component_pos_y" type="double"/>
      <Option value="200" name="component_width" type="double"/>
      <Option value="PointsLayer" name="name" type="QString"/>
      <Option value="true" name="outputs_collapsed" type="bool"/>
      <Option value="true" name="parameters_collapsed" type="bool"/>
    </Option>
    <Option name="VactorLayer" type="Map">
      <Option value="" name="color" type="QString"/>
      <Option name="comment" type="Map">
        <Option value="" name="color" type="QString"/>
        <Option value="" name="component_description" type="QString"/>
        <Option value="60" name="component_height" type="double"/>
        <Option value="600" name="component_pos_x" type="double"/>
        <Option value="15" name="component_pos_y" type="double"/>
        <Option value="100" name="component_width" type="double"/>
        <Option value="true" name="outputs_collapsed" type="bool"/>
        <Option value="true" name="parameters_collapsed" type="bool"/>
      </Option>
      <Option value="VactorLayer" name="component_description" type="QString"/>
      <Option value="30" name="component_height" type="double"/>
      <Option value="250" name="component_pos_x" type="double"/>
      <Option value="160" name="component_pos_y" type="double"/>
      <Option value="200" name="component_width" type="double"/>
      <Option value="VactorLayer" name="name" type="QString"/>
      <Option value="true" name="outputs_collapsed" type="bool"/>
      <Option value="true" name="parameters_collapsed" type="bool"/>
    </Option>
  </Option>
</Option>
```

Comment: Can you share your model and your data (at least a sample) for testing?

Comment: Nice to find the same issue I'm looking for a solution. I'm trying to create folders and files for each output of the iteration based on the value of an attribute. For example, I used the algorithm 'Create folder' filling precalculated field with the formula: '<path>/'|| attribute($currentfeature,'Name'). This returns a folder named attribute($currentfeature,'Name') but not the resulting value of the formula. For files, it won't even create it.